# Excel Formula to find Next Sheet in workbook

Tags: excel, reference, formula

I have a huge file with many sheets and in each sheet I need the same formula that references the next sheet in sequence, but only the sheet that follows it.
For example: 
Let's say I have sheets organized as follows in order from first sheet to last sheet (left to right):
"BOB"
"JIM"
"Larry"
"Tim"
"Joe"
...
The formula in "BOB" needs to refer to sheet "JIM", and the formula in "JIM" needs to refer to sheet "Larry", etc. There are dozens of sheets like this.

I've seen formulas that can refer to active sheet or current sheet, but is there a formula that can reference to the next sheet? This way I can just copy the formula into each sheet without modifying the formula's sheet reference each time.

Thanks!
EDIT: The sheets are not named after actual dates - I was just using that as an example to clearly state what I need; I guess it was a bad example. I'll correct that by replacing them with names.

Comment: That would work well except the sheets are not actually dates, I was using that as an example but didn't make that clear. I edited the original post.

Comment: Can you use VBA (UDF) or does it have to be a formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you place an ordered list of sheet names somewhere you could do it this way, though daresay there is a quicker way.

In A5

> =RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename"),1))

In A6 (which returns the next sheet)

> =INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(A5,A1:A3,0)+1)

[image]